# Example or classification of existentially closed modules

Tags: model-theory

In the language of modules, it suffices to restrict our view to *positive-primitive* formulas - that is to say, formulas with one existential quantifier and no negation.

And I mean *existentially closed* in the sense that any witness to a particular positive-primitive formula over the module is already in the module itself.

My intuition is that I should look along the lines of injective modules. Can anyone help by offering direction or perhaps an example / verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do primitive positive formulas only allow conjunctions, not disjunctions?  If so, then injective modules are existentially closed, but are a strictly stronger concept in that the equivalent for infinite conjunctions are allowed.

The concept you're after is that of [algebraically compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_compact_module) module (also known as pure inective module).  Here's a link to a paper by [Prest](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1148/01/covered/MIMS_ep2008_83.pdf) that talks about some their properties.

[Baer's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Baer.27s_criterion) asserts existential closure under infinite conjunctions.  Let
$$
(\exists m) r_1 m = m_1 \wedge r_2 m = m_2 \wedge \cdots
$$
be a particular formula, where $R$ is your coefficient ring, $M$ a module over $R$, with $r_i \in R$ and $m_i \in M$.  Then consider the ideal $I$ generated by $r_i$ in $R$.  There the map that sends $r_i$ to $m_i$ is a homomorphism from $I$ to $M$ if and only if that formula is consistent.  (There's a homomorphism if and only if the formula does not imply $s = s'$ for two distinct elements $s, s' \in R$.)